# How to access GitHub "variables" from GitHub Actions scripts? (env. doesn't work)

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to access GitHub SECRETS and VARIABLES set at the Repo level and at the Organization level for a GitHub "Actions" script.

Here is the script:

```
name: CI (pip)
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ['ubuntu-latest']
        python-version: [3.9]   # installed version on Dreamhost
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    timeout-minutes: 10
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true

      - name: First Test
        run: |
          echo ORG_NAME   = ${{ env.ORG_NAME}}
          echo MY_NAME    = ${{ env.MY_NAME}}
          echo MY_SECRET  = ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}

      - name: Second Test
        env:
          ORG_NAME_ENV:        ${{ env.ORG_NAME }}
          MY_NAME_ENV:         ${{ env.MY_NAME }}
          MY_SECRET:           ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
        run: |
          echo ORG_NAME_ENV = $ORG_NAME_ENV
          echo MY_SECRET = $MY_SECRET
          echo SHA256 = `echo $MY_SECRET | openssl sha256`
```

This just doesn't work. The `secrets.MY_SECRET` gets set, but `env.ORG_NAME` and `env.MY_NAME` do not get set.

Here is what the config looks like:

Organization level actions secrets and variables:
[image]

Repo secrets:

[image]

Repo level variables:

[image]

I can access the secrets, but not the variables.

Here is what the output looks like:

[image]

Oh, MY_SECRET=`secret`, in case you don't want to do the hash search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration variables are accessed via the `vars` context, not `env`.

See:

- [`vars` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context)
- [Using the `vars` context to access configuration variable values](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values)